# Convert a multi-element character into different independent elements in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need help in converting a character from several elements to independent elements.

Example:

```
 cad <- c("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11")
 cad
 [1] "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11"
```

to

```
 a <- 0:11
 data.frame(a)



 cad
1   0
2   1
3   2
4   3
5   4
6   5
7   6
8   7
9   8
10  9
11 10
12 11
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `scan` from `base R` which basically extracts the elements into a `vector` and can be wrapped into `data.frame`

```
data.frame(cad = scan(text = cad, what = numeric()))
#   cad
#1    0
#2    1
#3    2
#4    3
#5    4
#6    5
#7    6
#8    7
#9    8
#10   9
#11  10
#12  11
```

---

Or another option is `read.table`

```
read.table(text = gsub(" ", "\n", cad), header = FALSE, col.names = 'cad')
#   cad
#1    0
#2    1
#3    2
#4    3
#5    4
#6    5
#7    6
#8    7
#9    8
#10   9
#11  10
#12  11
```

---

Or another option is `strsplit` with `unlist` (would take care of multiple strings as well)

```
data.frame(cad = unlist(strsplit(cad, "\\s+")))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `strsplit` to split text on whitespace and wrap it in `data.frame`

```
data.frame(cad = strsplit(cad, "\\s+")[[1]])

#   cad
#1    0
#2    1
#3    2
#4    3
#5    4
#6    5
#7    6
#8    7
#9    8
#10   9
#11  10
#12  11
```